# Parse Image File persisting in app after deleted from parse backend

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am developing an app that uses parse to store and receive pictures. The pictures are taken on the phone, displayed on the app, saved in parse, and can be retrieved through Parse. I am fairly new to parse so i'm not sure if the following behavior is normal. When I download a picture from parse I am using the following code:

```
if let image1File = user?["image1"] as? PFFile {

image1File.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if !(error != nil) {
            imgOne.image = UIImage(data:imageData)
        }
    }
}
```

This code is in `viewDidLoad` so the picture will show when the `viewController` loads. However, when I manually delete the picture from parse myself, not through code, the picture persists and will continue to load until I delete the app from the simulator and reload it. Is this a parse/simulator/code issue?

Note: I am testing this on the simulator, not an actual phone

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: But this is not a parse issue at all. This is a either a new developer or an inexperienced developer not reading documentation. This is parse doing exactly what it's supposed to do. Parse caches files for numerous reasons. 1) performance enhancements. 2) the one you should be concerned with, reducing API requests. This is a big deal, especially if you have a scaleable app, you only get 30/rps unless you wanna pay of course. So no. In short. It's a good thing! Get familiar with their documentation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be several possible reasons for this to happen. First of all, Parse stores images in Amazon-S3 and what you essentially receive is an absolute link to that file. When you delete a parse object, that has a file reference attribute, the original file might not get deleted at all. That is why Parse has a `Clear Unused Files` from your Parse-app feature afterall.

Secondly, at several levels, images might be cached for obvious performance reasons. So, even if an image file is deleted, it persists at several locations for certain amounts of time, which might be another reason why you experience this issue.

But, from experience, you should code the logic in such a way that, if a particular object is deleted by the user, you should not pull anything related to that object the next time at all. Also, you may use a regular [cron job to clean up unused files](https://www.parse.com/questions/deleting-unused-files-in-regular-cron-job) on your Parse-app.